# Vscode : Open file locally using Remote-SSH through integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server, vscode-remote

I am using Remote-SSH plugin for remote development and would like to open a file in the existing editor using an integrated terminal (which is running a remote shell). A similar issue was posted on fit repository but it doesn't seem to work now.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/766

**Local Machine**
1.41.1
26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
Windowsx64

**Remote Machine**
1.41.0
9579eda04fdb3a9bba2750f15193e5fafe16b959
CentOsx64

Can you help me to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68090934/319542

---

You shouldn't have to do anything. VSCode automatically sets the path/PATH to the `code`  in the path/PATH environment variable depending on your shell. See [this response](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/766#issuecomment-504632685). You might be overwriting your path/PATH like I was. I was accidentally overwriting  `path` in `~/.cshrc` and `PATH` in `~/.bashrc` and was running into the same issue. After fixing it, I can run `code` on the command line. `which code` returns the location of the command.

Until I spent time to figure it out, I was using the two methods mentioned below. Both of which worked for me in `bash`; you can modify it for your shell as you see fit. But really fix your path/PATH rather than using these methods.

1. Adding location of `code` to the PATH in `~/.bashrc`

   `export PATH=${VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE%/*}/bin:$PATH`

OR

2. Setting alias to `code` in `~/.bashrc`

   `alias code="${VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE%/*}/bin/code"`

---

More on `path` vs. `PATH` [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118340/7778) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532155/7778)

Comment: I ended up using the second approach, setting the path for code, but I guess I am also overwriting my PATH variable as you said, I will try to get rid of that. Thanks.