# Open files from remote ssh host in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm using using VSCode Remote SSH from my laptop (Linux) to work on projects that resides on a Linux host.

If I open an internal terminal in VSCode I can open files from the host by doing `code some_file.txt`. I frequently want to be able to do the same from terminals that are not originating from VSCode.

Is there anyway to open files in the VSCode-server while connected to a standard (Non VSCode internal) terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62201080/is-it-possible-to-use-the-code-command-in-sshed-terminal-to-open-vs-code-on-l), I learned that if you open an integrated terminal and find the `VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI` environment variable, and set it to the same value in the non-integrated terminal, then run `code` from the code server install directory `~/.vscode-server`, it will work.  That article didn't mention that you can have more than one install in the `~/.vscode-server` directory.  The current install can be extracted from the `VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MODE` variable, it looks like this:

```
$ echo $VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE
/home/<user>/.vscode-server/bin/054a9295330880ed74ceaedda236253b4f39a335/node
```

Just chop off the `node` and add `bin`, and so run something like

```
$ /home/<user>/.vscode-server/bin/054a9295330880ed74ceaedda236253b4f39a335/bin/code myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured this out by investigative the environment in the internal terminal. I have a small script that I source that looks up the correct paths for the latest opened vscode instance. I'll add it here once I'm at a computer.

Comment: `/run/user/$(id -u)/vscode-ipc-*` might now be `/tmp/vscode-ipc-*`. It is for me on VSCode 1.64.1.

Comment: I'm looking at this now and the `code` script is in `.../bin/remote-cli/code`, not `.../bin/code`. I can't say if this is platform-specific or version-specific, I'm just telling what I see. See also comment by @brian-horakh where he uses this path.

Answer (score -1):

C. R. Oldham's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67549333) covers the technical detail of why/how.

If you want a 1-liner that works as an `alias` in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```bash
# Open file in most recently-connected remote VSCode session.
alias code=$'VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI=/run/user/`id -u`/$(ls -lt /run/user/`id -u`/ | egrep \.sock$ | head -1 | awk \'END {print $NF}\') `ls -lt ~/.vscode-server/bin/** | fgrep bin/remote-cli/code | head -1 | awk \'END {print $NF}\'`'
```

Comment: `ls -lt ~/.vscode-server/bin/** | fgrep bin/remote-cli/code` section of the statement above produces zero results. 

I would suggest this:
`alias code="${HOME}/.vscode-server/bin/$(ls -t1 ${HOME}/.vscode-server/bin | head -n 1)/bin/remote-cli/code"
`