# VSCode - remote SSH - can't find code executable in vscode-server directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

I'm using VSCode and the official remote-ssh extension.

I would like to be able to write `code /path/to/file` in an ssh terminal or in the vscode integrated terminal in a remote window in order to open a file/folder in vscode remote.

I am aware that I can use `code --folder-uri=vscode-remote://ssh-remote+ADDRESS/path/to/file` from the local machine's terminal, but I want to be able to run a command from within the integrated vscode terminal and any other terminal session where I've ssh'd into the remote machine)

Currently, if I run `code` from a remote terminal it opens up a new vscode window on the remote machine.

To achieve this goal, in the past I've used the following alias on the remote machine:

`alias code="${VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE%/*}/bin/code"`

Which looks for the `code` executable in `~/.vscode-server/bin/<COMMIT_ID>/bin` before defaulting to the local `/bin/code`.

I got that alias from [this related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62201080/is-it-possible-to-use-the-code-command-in-sshed-terminal-to-open-vs-code-on-l).

However, this doesn't seem to work right now.

Upon closer inspection, it appears that there is no `code` executable in the `vscode-server` directory.

[image: available files in code-serverk]

How can I fix this?

Both machines are running MacOS and visual studio code version `f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326`, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to be able to run `code` from the integrated terminal when running VSCode with the "remote ssh" extension. In my case, the "remote" is a Linux box (named "aorus" below), and I want to use VSCode from a laptop running macOS (named "mbp").

As for you, I used to use the `VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE` trick. Recently, I had to change the alias since `code` (or `code-insiders` in my case) wasn't available in `bin/` anymore. It seems it has been moved to `bin/remote-cli`. The correct alias (tested with vscode 1.64.2):

```sh
alias code="${VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE%/*}/bin/remote-cli/code"
```

If you also want this to work from other ssh sessions (not just inside the integrated terminal), you can create a short script that I called `coder` (`r` for "remote") which I have in `~/bin` on my remote ("aorus"). Note that you need to be able to reach the local machine from your remote (I do that with Tailscale). The script looks like this:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

set -ex
remotehost=$(hostname)
localhost=mbp

cmd="code"

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        cmd+=" --file-uri \"vscode-remote://ssh-remote+$remotehost$(readlink -f "$1")\""
    elif [ -d "$1" ]; then
        cmd+=" --folder-uri \"vscode-remote://ssh-remote+$remotehost$(readlink -f "$1")\""
    else
        cmd+=" $1"
    fi
    shift
done

exec ssh $localhost -q -t -x "exec bash -l -c '$cmd'"
```

On my Mac, when running VSCode connected remotely to my Linux box, I can type this in the integrated terminal to open the file `main.go` present on my remote Linux box:

```sh
coder main.go
```

The reason I have to wrap `code` in `bash -l` is due to the fact that `ssh`, by default, runs in a non-login shell, which means that the `~/.bashrc` on my Mac isn't picked up, meaning `code` isn't in the PATH. The error message looks like this:

```
bash:1: command not found: code
```

Another note: there is a shorter syntax documented [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_connect-to-a-remote-host-from-the-terminal):

```sh
ssh -q -t -x mbp bash -l -c "code --remote=ssh-remote+aorus main.go"
```

I don't use this syntax is because this method isn't able to know whether you are opening just a single file (which should be open in the most recent VSCode remote session) or a folder (which should be open as a new VSCode remote session).

Finally, if you are using VSCode Insiders, you can create a symlink so that the command `code` works on your local machine (in my case, on my Mac):

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/code-insiders /usr/local/bin/code
```

Comment: how can I adapt your `coder` script for a macOS host?


I get this error: 


    `readlink: illegal option -- f`
    `usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]`

Comment: Ah, right, `readlink -f` only works with the readlink that comes with GNU coreutils. I'll think of something.

Comment: I ended up using `brew install coreutils` to install coreutils on the macOS host and then substituted `readlink` with `greadlink` and all worked fine. However, I'm still at a loss why I can't just figure out a solution that would work with the `code` command... as that worked before and I'm not sure what's stopping it from working now.

Comment: I just found out that macOS's `readlink` does exactly the same as GNU's `readlink -f`.

Regarding `code` from within the integrated terminal, it should still work, no need to use the `coder` script above.

From the integrated terminal, if you run

`echo $PATH | tr -s : $'\n' | grep vscode`

you will see that another `code`, specific to the remote session. Its path looks like this: 

`~/.vscode-server/bin/<somehash>/bin/remote-cli/code`

Unfortunately, this method doesn't work outside of the integrated terminal, which is why I use the above `coder` script.

Comment: Interesting... because I had a solution that worked outside of the integrated terminal before as well... if only I had a time machine!

Answer (score 1):

As already explained by maelvls the path has been changed.
But if you use it outside integrated terminal you will got message

`Command is only available in WSL or inside a Visual Studio Code terminal`

To avoid this you need to `export VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI` in your .bashrc .

Use this script in your .bashrc

```
export VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI=`ls -t /run/user/1012/vscode-ipc-* | head -n1`
alias code="~/.vscode-server/bin/*/bin/remote-cli/code"
```

If you want to open your file in your current visual studio use `-r` option.

```
code -r tes.txt
```

Note :
I can't call `VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE` so I use full path, it is working well
I don't know if `VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI` will show in different location, just check it in your integrated terminal visual studio code

tested on remote server Centos 7
local macOS Monterey version 12.2
Visual Studio Code Version: 1.64.2 (Universal)
Commit: f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326
extension : remote-ssh